# VR view for the web : error unable to load texture

Tags: google-vr

I try to use vr view for the web in localhost. https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web

My code is :

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
    function onVrViewLoad(){
    var view = new VRView.Player('#vrview', { image : 'img.jpg', is_stereo: false, width: 857, height: 297});
    }
</script>

<div id='vrview'></div>
```

My error is :

> Render: unable to load texture from "file: ... img.jpg"

I already read every posts on this problem.
I try to use the cardboard camera converter but I have already an equirectangular-panoramic image and it says :

> "Conversion error: no valid right eye image found in the XMP metadata.
>   This might not be a valid Cardboard Camera image."

I don't know why it doesn't work.
Can you help me ?

PS : sorry for my english...